# Which constructor is called on TextWriterTraceListener when listener defined in config?

Tags: c#, constructor, trace, system.diagnostics, tracelistener

When a `TextWriterTraceListener` is defined in config...

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="MyApp" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <clear/>
          <add name="File" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="D:\trace\MyApp.log" traceOutputOptions="None">
            <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="Warning" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="2" />
  </system.diagnostics>
```

...does anyone know which of the constructors gets called by .Net when the TraceListeners collection is created?  there are several....

```
public TextWriterTraceListener()
public TextWriterTraceListener(Stream stream)
public TextWriterTraceListener(Stream stream, string name)
public TextWriterTraceListener(TextWriter writer)
public TextWriterTraceListener(TextWriter writer, string name) 
public TextWriterTraceListener(string fileName)
public TextWriterTraceListener(string fileName, string name)
```

...I'm guessing possibly the last one? I suppose it depends on how `System.Diagnostics` handles the `initializeData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it's this one...

```
public TextWriterTraceListener(string fileName)
```